# How to count word similarity between two pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, cosine-similarity

Here's my first dataframe `df1`

```
Id   Text
1    Asoy Geboy Ngebut
2    Asoy kita Geboy 
3    Bersatu kita Teguh
```

Here's my second dataframe `df2`

```
Id   Text
1    Bersatu Kita
2    Asoy Geboy Jalanan
```

Similarity Matrix, columns is `Id` from `df1`, rows is `Id` from `df2`

```
       1      2      3
1      0   0.33      1  
2   0.66   0.66      0
```

Note:

`0` value in (1,1) and (3,2) because no text similar

`1` value in (3,1) is because of `Bersatu` and `Kita' (Id` 1`on`df2`is avalilable in Id`3`on`df1`

`0.33` is counted because of 1 of 3 words similar

`0.66` is counted because of 2 of 3 words similar

Comment: Have you had a chance to test the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to compute a `set` intersection:

```
l1 = [set(x.split()) for x in df1['Text'].str.lower()]
l2 = [set(x.split()) for x in df2['Text'].str.lower()]

pd.DataFrame([[len(s1&s2)/len(s1) for s1 in l1] for s2 in l2],
             columns=df1['Id'], index=df2['Id'])
```

output:

```
Id         1         2         3
Id                              
1   0.000000  0.333333  0.666667
2   0.666667  0.666667  0.000000
```

*NB. Note that the condition on the denominator is not fully clear, for `{teguh, kita, bersatu}` vs `{kita, bersatu}` I count `2/3 = 0.666`*